# ASP HttpClient GetAsync is not responding, nor timing out

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an Instagram API client on ASP MVC using HttpClient, I'm trying to make a get request but it fails without throwing exception or responding and doesn't respond to my timeout. Here is my code:

```
 public class InstagramService
 {
    private HttpClient Client = new HttpClient {
       BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.instagram.com/v1/"),
       Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)
    };
    public async Task<InstagramUser> GetInstagramUser(long? userId = null)
    {
       InstagramUser User = null;
       string Parameter = (userId == null) ? "self" : userId.ToString();
       try {
          var response = await Client.GetAsync("users/" + Parameter + "/" + GetAccessToken());
          if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
              User = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<InstagramUser>();
          }
      }catch(Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
          Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
      }
      return User;
    }

    private string GetAccessToken()
    {
        return "?access_token=" + DB.config_det_sys.Single(i => i.codigo == "ACCESS_TOKEN_INSTAGRAM" && i.estado == true).Valor;
    }

 }
```

**EDIT**

Here I add how I call my service on the Home Controller, I will still test changing the controller to async Task

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private InstagramService IGService = new InstagramService();
    public ActionResult About()
    {
       var apiCall = IGService.GetInstagramUser();
       var model = apiCall.Result;
       return View(model);
    }
}
```

I tested on Postman trying to make the API call and it indeed worked, so where I'm failing to catch errors?

Comment: How is the code being called? Make sure you are not making any blocking calls higher up the call stack

Comment: @Nkosi Here, I added a fragment of how I intend on callying the methods

Comment: check Stephen Cleary's answer. As I suspected you were making a blocking call on `apiCall.Result` which can result in a deadlock. Convert the action to use async/await

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
var model = apiCall.Result;
```

As I describe on my blog, [you shouldn't block on asynchronous code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). It can cause a deadlock.

Instead of `Result`, use `await`:

```
var model = await apiCall;
```

Comment: I have a small doubt, If I create another private async method for the service that calls the GET Endpoints (because I need to add the access token on every call), calling three async awaitables could impact performance?

Comment: @Forcefield: Three async calls would not have a noticeable performance change at all.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Stephen's answer, update the controller's action to be `async` all the way.

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    private InstagramService IGService = new InstagramService();
    public async Task<ActionResult> About() {
       var model = await IGService.GetInstagramUser();
       return View(model);
    }
}
```